# Trouble getting Jest mocks to work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm having some trouble getting Jest mocking to work.

I'm trying to unit-test a module that has some asynchronous bits in driven by [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

My understanding is currently that:

- I can use the [`jest.mock()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html#content) method to mock the entire module.
- I can mock the methods `request.get`, `request.post`, etc to make them synchronous and pass particular responses by creating a file inside a `__mocks__/` dir.
- Jest will automock modules from the `__mocks__/` when they're required/imported.
- I can override the `request` dependency by loading it after I import the module that imports it into the test file.

I think I'm missing something obvious.

Module I want to test:

```
// module.js
import request from 'request'

export default function foo() {
  let options = { /* ... */ }
  let callback = function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      return /* Response A */
    } else {
      return /* Response B */
    }
  }

  request.post(options, callback);
}
```

Mocked request module:

```
// __mock__/request.js

function post(options, callback) {
  callback(undefined, {statusCode: 200})
}

const request = jest.genMockFromModule('request')
request.post = post

export default request;
```

Module test:

```
// module.spec.js
import foo from './module'
jest.mock('request')

test('should return response A', function () {
  expect(foo()).toBe(/* Response A */)
});
```

When I run the module tests,

- the `request` module does not appear to be mocked, and
- foo does not generate either "Response A" or "Response B"

Anyone know how to mock this to test it properly?

Comment: as your function `foo` does not return anything the test will not work. Have you logged `request` in your `module.js` file during the test, is it really not a mocked, cause the settings looks fine so far.

Comment: That makes sense. This might also be complicated by not returning a Promise from `foo()` that I can use an `expect` on later, per [Jest's Async documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html). Let me give that a try and report back.

Answer (score -2):

Moving `jest.mock('request')` before `import ...` will help you I guess.